networkPolicy stops working if I add ports section
I have two namespaces:
source-ns and destination-ns
I want to allow all traffic from source-ns to destination-ns on port 80.
This policy works fine:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-port-80
  namespace: destination-ns
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          access-to-destination-ns: allow
  - from:
    - podSelector: {}

running test from source namespace:

nc -vz service.destination-ns 80
service.destination-ns (10.1.2.221:80) open

however if I try to lock it down to specific port, it stops working:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-port-80
  namespace: destination-ns
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          access-to-destination-ns: allow
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
  - from:
    - podSelector: {}

running test from source namespace:

nc -vz service.destination-ns 80
nc: service.destination-ns (10.1.2.221:80): Connection timed out

Running on AKS with azure SNI and calico, single linux node pool, single node.
service spec:
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.1.2.221
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.1.2.221
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  type: ClusterIP
  ...

since this reproduction scenario seems to work as expected, posting my actual resources where I can't get this to work:
source namespace:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/sync-options: Delete=false
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Namespace","metadata":{"annotations":{"argocd.argoproj.io/sync-options":"Delete=false"},"labels":{"access-to-airbyte":"allow","argocd.argoproj.io/instance":"namespaces","istio-injection":"disabled","owner":"infrastructure"},"name":"bitbucket-runners"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2024-04-12T12:50:07Z"
  labels:
    access-to-airbyte: allow
    argocd.argoproj.io/instance: namespaces
    istio-injection: disabled
    kubernetes.io/metadata.name: bitbucket-runners
    owner: infrastructure
  name: bitbucket-runners
  resourceVersion: "12256074"
  uid: 7fae10ad-0ed8-4d27-bbe1-fc2884e18164
spec:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes
status:
  phase: Active


destination namespace:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/sync-options: Delete=false
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Namespace","metadata":{"annotations":{"argocd.argoproj.io/sync-options":"Delete=false"},"labels":{"argocd.argoproj.io/instance":"namespaces","istio-injection":"disabled","owner":"data"},"name":"airbyte"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2024-04-10T10:28:36Z"
  labels:
    argocd.argoproj.io/instance: namespaces
    istio-injection: disabled
    kubernetes.io/metadata.name: airbyte
    owner: data
  name: airbyte
  resourceVersion: "9947279"
  uid: 5bc8e393-de77-4e3d-9eb5-96dedf8fceb1
spec:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes
status:
  phase: Active

net policy with ports which does not allow to connect to services on port 80 in destination ns from source ns (but works once ports section is removed):
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-traffic-to-airbyte
  namespace: airbyte
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          access-to-airbyte: allow
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
  - from:
    - podSelector: {}

the service I'm trying to test:

airbyte-airbyte-api-server-svc                 ClusterIP   10.2.10.146           80/TCP         26d     app.kubernetes.io/instance=airbyte,app.kubernetes.io/name=airbyte-api-server


The issue in your example is likely the placement and scope of the ports specification within the ingress section. To fix the issue, the ports specification should be included within each from block where it's intended to apply.

It is intended to apply in the source-ns to destination-ns, the second from block is for allowing all traffic between pods in the destination-ns.

Your initial Network Policy works because it allows all ingress traffic from any pods in namespaces with the label access-to-destination-ns: allow, as well as from any pods within the destination-ns itself, without any restriction on ports. When you add the ports section to restrict traffic to TCP port 80, you need to ensure that the structure of the ingress rule correctly applies this port restriction only to the intended sources. The issue in your non-working example is likely the placement and scope of the ports specification within the ingress section. To fix the issue, the ports specification should be included within each from block where it's intended to apply.
Example setup to configure the network policy to allow traffic on port 80 from source-ns to destination-ns.
Create the namespaces source-ns and destination-ns
kubectl create namespace source-ns
kubectl create namespace destination-ns


Label source-ns so that the network policy can identify it
kubectl label namespaces source-ns access-to-destination-ns=allow

Deploy a Sample Application and Service in destination-ns
kubectl run http-server --image=nginx --namespace=destination-ns

Create a service to expose the HTTP server (My sample app)
kubectl expose pod http-server --port=80 --target-port=80 --namespace=destination-ns

apply a network policy to allow traffic on port 80 from source-ns to all pods in destination-ns
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-port-80
  namespace: destination-ns
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          access-to-destination-ns: allow
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80

You can apply the same using
kubectl apply -f allow-port-80.yaml


Test the connectivity from a pod in source-ns to the service in destination-ns
kubectl get pods -n source-ns
kubectl exec -it test-pod -n source-ns -- nc -vz http-server.destination-ns 80



The output http-server.destination-ns (10.0.219.12:80) open indicates that the network policy is correctly configured and functioning. Your test-pod in source-ns can successfully connect to the http-server service in destination-ns on port 80
If your configuration aims to allow:

Traffic on port 80 from source-ns to all pods in destination-ns using a namespaceSelector that filters traffic from namespaces labeled access-to-destination-ns: allow- You should specify the ports array within the same from clause that includes the namespaceSelector.

All intra-namespace traffic within destination-ns without any port restrictions - You should have a separate from clause that specifies a podSelector with an empty set of selectors, which effectively selects all pods within the namespace.


In that case your network policy will be -
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-port-80
  namespace: destination-ns
spec:
  podSelector: {}  # Applies to all pods in the namespace
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          access-to-destination-ns: allow
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80  # Restrict this rule to TCP port 80
  - from:
    - podSelector: {}  # Allows all traffic from pods within the same namespace

Here, the first ingress entry allows traffic on TCP port 80 from any namespace that has the label access-to-destination-ns: allow, effectively allowing traffic from source-ns to destination-ns on port 80. -   The second ingress entry allows all traffic from any pod within destination-ns. This entry does not specify a ports section, so it allows traffic on all ports.

References:

Use Calico network policy to secure pod traffic
Networking and connectivity for mission-critical workloads on Azure


that is how I understood it and how I'm trying to achieve it, isn't your last example exactly the same which is not working for me?

yes, it is, that's why I shared the HTTP server example as well. See if that approach works for you.

it works when I follow this step by step, edited original post with my actual resources, because I can't  identify meaningful difference between these two scenarios

What do you see when you do kubectl get namespace bitbucket-runners --show-labels
and kubectl get namespace airbyte --show-labels and kubectl describe netpol allow-traffic-to-airbyte -n airbyte . If labels are correct and there is no internal connectivity issue within airbyte, try testing connectivity from a pod in the bitbucket-runners namespace directly to the service in airbyte using kubectl exec -it [pod-name] -n bitbucket-runners -- nc -vz airbyte-airbyte-api-server-svc.airbyte 80.

If all these checks pass but the issue still persists, consider any network isolation or firewall rules outside Kubernetes that might be impacting network traffic.

for now I shoved this into the backlog, was taking too much time to figure out, will post back once I return to it.
